# Django - clean() with hidden form

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm having an issue here, my def `clean()` is not working with my hidden `form`.

I have three `forms` where I'm using `jquery` to hide it with a `select` so if for example, I want `form1` just I have to pick `form1` and it will hide the others 2.

Now I'm trying to use `clean()` but when I get my `raise ValidationError` I can't see it because my `form` is hidden.

So I need to click on `form1` and after that, I can see my `error`

Is there a possible way to see my `error` even if its hidden?

Because sometimes I don't know why I'm getting an error until I click on `form1`.

I have been looking for a possible solution and found nothing.

**template**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
{{ titulo }}
<hr/>
<br/>

  {% if messages %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.tags %}<div  class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
  {% endif %}

  <center>
    <label for="protocolo">Protocolo de Activos</label>
      <select id="protocolo" name="protocolo">
      {% for x,y in form.fields.protocolo.choices %}
          <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.fields.protocolo.value == x %} selected{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select>
  </center>
<br>

<div id="form1" style="display:none;">
  <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Datos" />
  </form>
</div>

<script>
    $('#protocolo').on('change',function(){
         var selection = $(this).val();
        switch(selection){
        case "form1":
        $("#form1").show()
       break;
        default:
        $("#form1").hide()
        }
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I'm using `jquery` to `show()` and `hide()` `form1` .

This code is working ok if `name` exists I'll get `Error` but I'll see that message when I click on my `select` and pick `form1`

I want to see it just when I hit my `submit`... Is it possible?

**Note**:

This time I have only one `form` as `form1` but I'll have to add more soon, that's why I'm using a `select` with `Jquery`.

**Thanks!!**

**EDIT:**

**forms.py**

```
class userForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ["name"]

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
            name,created = user.get_or_create(name=name)
        except Exception, e:
            raise ValidationError('Error, already exists')
        return super(userForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Views.py**

```
def user_form(request):
    titulo = "Activos"
    form1 = userForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset = user.objects.all()
    context = {
    "form1": form,
    "queryset": queryset,
    }
    if form1.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Has been added')
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "user.html", context)
```

I just edited my code with `views` and `form`.

Once I go to my to my form and I try to register a user that already exists I get the error message, that's ok. But I have a Jquery effect explained before which prevents me from seeing my error messages unless I click on my select and pick my form, then I can see my flag error `Error, already exists`

I would like to see `Error, already exists` once I hit on `submit` and redirects me.

`clean()` method only works when I select my `form`

Comment: Clean method in a form class is not the place to be creating model instances.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Where do you suggest me to use clean method? I tried on Views.py but didn't work for me

Comment: The clean method is called automatically when you do form.is_valid(). Why don't you edit your question to include your view, your form and also explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Just edited my code @e4c5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you don't need to override the clean method here [because](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/)

> The ModelForm.clean() method sets a flag that makes the model
>   validation step validate the uniqueness of model fields that are
>   marked as unique, unique_together or unique_for_date|month|year.
>
> If you would like to override the clean() method and maintain this
>   validation, you must call the parent class’s clean() method.

So all your need is
forms.py

```
class userForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ["name"]
```

that's it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant. I don't need clean() method? I wanted to avoid the jquery select and show name already exists error in template

Comment: That's automatially taken care of by ModelForm as explained in my answe. Please refer to the linked documentation for further details

Comment: Thank you, I found what I needed. Worked as expected!

Comment: Glad to have helped